# Active Record: eager_load performs unexpected deduplication on results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an active record query where I select objects based on the join of another table and a where clause. The result might include the same object several times and this is the desired behaviour.

For my example query, I get 3 results of which 2 rows are identical.

I now want to eager load another association. If I use `includes`, the query still produces 3 rows, but the generated query is suboptimal:

```
puts l.count # 3
l = l.includes(:name)
puts l.count #3
puts l.to_a.count #3
```

By forcing the use of `eager_load`, the generated query is optimized, but somehow I lose my duplicate row:

```
puts l.count # 3
l = l.eager_load(:name)
puts l.count # 2
puts l.to_a.count #2
```

The strange thing is, if I manually execute the generated query, I do get 3 rows. This means active record performs the deduplication. Why does this happen and is there a way to work around this issue?

Something I noticed during my experiments to get an optimal query (and that might be related) is that `l.count` and `l.to_a.count` not always produce the same result:

```
puts l.count # 3
l = l.joins(:name).includes(:name)
puts l.count # 3
puts l.to_a.count # 2
```